# IQueryable<> does not contain a definition for Query - Checking if record exists in Database C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, uwp, iqueryable

I found several topics but they do not answer my problem.

With help of other topics answers I came with code as following:

```
private void CheckIfProductExists()
{
    using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(
        new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DB_PATH))
    {

        List<Product> myCollection = conn.Table<Product>().ToList<Product>();
        IQueryable<Product> query = myCollection.AsQueryable();
        var checkProductName = query.Query<Product>(
            "SELECT COUNT(*) from [Product] where [Name] like '@name'", 
            conn);
        checkProductName.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", DescriptionBox.Text);
        int ProductExist = checkProductName.ExecuteScalar();

        if (ProductExist > 0)
        {
            //Product exist
        }
        else
        {
            //Product doesn't exist.
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error as in title at

```
.Query<Product>
```

Any suggestions what might be wrong with my code?

Comment: What error? What is the Product? What is your Db table like?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to do `conn.Query<Product>`? http://www.rbdocumentation.com/html/19d38743-7935-a894-7551-513c6686bd50.htm

Comment: error says: IQueryable<Product> does not contain a definition for Query. Product is a class for Table.

Comment: so the table is called Product too

Comment: if I do conn.Query<Product> I get errors at Parameters and ExecuteScalar saying exactly the same: List<Product> does not contain a definition for Parameters or ExecuteScalar

Comment: I think you just want `var checkProductName = query.Query<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) from [Product] where [Name] like ?", DescriptionBox.Text);`  That should give you a list of the matches, so no need for the `ExecuteScalar`, instead a `SingleOrDefault` or just `checkProductName[0]` would give you the returned value.

Comment: but it doesnt resolve the error at Query<Product> that says that IQueryable<Product> does not contain a definition for Query

Comment: @positiveperspective `IQueryable` doesn't have a `Query` method.  You have to call the `Query` method on the connection.  That's the fix.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that your where clause is going to work.  You have a `like`, but no wildcards unless you expect them to be in the `DescriptionBox.Text`

Comment: There *is* no `Query<T>` method on `IQueryable<T>`. Where did you get that example from? This could be a simple misunderstanding / wrong library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the `Query` method on the wrong type of object.  Instead you can just call `ExecuteScalar` on the `SQLiteConnection` based on the [`SQLiteConnection` documentation](http://www.rbdocumentation.com/html/ee6c5c5e-365a-bd25-fbc9-63c601b3c1b8.htm)

```
private void CheckIfProductExists()
{
    using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(
        new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DB_PATH))
    {
        int productCount = conn.ExecuteScalar<int>(
            "SELECT COUNT(*) from [Product] where [Name] like ?", 
            DescriptionBox.Text);

        if (productCount  > 0)
        {
            //Product exist
        }
        else
        {
            //Product doesn't exist.
        }
    }
}
```

Note that right now that `like` is going to depend on wild cards added to the `DescriptionBox.Text`.  So if the value is "car" it will only match "car", but if it's "car%" it would match anything that starts with "car".  I'm not sure if that's what you really want or not.

Comment: Thank You, it seems that Your solution is the answer to my problem. As in most cases, the solution is more obvious than it seems to be.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank You juharr